# MassAssignmentSecurity error while attr_accessible has been called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passwords

I'm following along with [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users?version=3.2#sec-an_encrypted_password) and at one point, it tells me to

> ... add password and password_confirmation attributes to the User model [...] Unlike the other attributes we’ve seen so far, the password attributes will be virtual—they will only exist temporarily in memory, and will not be persisted to the database.

And

> As we’ll see in Section 6.3.4, these virtual attributes are implemented automatically by has_secure_password.

My model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :email, :is_admin, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password_digest, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: true
end
```

So now when I try to create a new user;

```
User.create(name: "Foo Bar", email: "foo@bar.net", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
```

I get the following error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password, password_confirmation
```

Why?!

Comment: I feel like this should work too. Have you done the usual trick? Re-migrating the database and restarting the rails server?

Comment: Ah, remigrating did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @garbagecollection Could you promote your comment into an answer so the OP can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues seemed as though the password and password_confirmation columns were missing in the database.

As per the comment, re-migrating and restarting the server would fix this problem.